# Equivalence of Helmholtz Free Energy and Work

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

Using the canonical ensemble, where $\rho$ is the probability of finding a microstate with energy E, and Helmholtz Free Energy F,

$$\rho = \exp\left(\frac{F-E}{kT}\right)$$

We get the following microstate equation:

$$ln(\rho)=(F-E)/kT$$
$$E=-kln(\rho)T+F$$

Going to the macro state, where $\langle E \rangle = U$,
$$\langle E \rangle=-k \langle ln(\rho) \rangle T + F$$
$$U=-k \langle ln(\rho) \rangle T + F$$

And then using the Gibbs Free Energy we get something close to the fundamental thermodynamic relation:

$$S=-k\langle ln(\rho)\rangle$$

$$U=TS+F$$
$$dU=TdS+dF$$

Comparing with the fundamental thermodynamic relation for a reversible process (and taking the convention of work done by the system),

$$dU=dQ + dW=TdS-PdV$$

Why is it necessarily true that, $dF=-PdV$ ? Maybe posing the question a different way, is there some other a priori postulate that leads to this conclusion?

Also, we know that the Helmholtz Free Energy is related to the partition function and the normalizing factor of the probability distribution. What physical significance does this have when we equate the Helmholtz Free Energy to work done to the system?

Edit: Assume constant temperature, isothermic process. As someone correctly pointed out, $\partial F = -P \partial V$. My question regarding this relationship remains.

Comment: True, that's definitely the case in non isothermic process. However, $dQ=TdS + SdT$, leaving my question about the free energy and work W in tact.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, it's just an infinitesimal amount of energy added to the system. I stated in my question it's a reversible process.

Comment: If in equilibrium, is dQ/T not the exact differential of dS? (genuine question)

Comment: Oh... yes, that makes sense. I hadn't thought about changes in temperature too much between states. I guess adiabatic processes. But is there any reason for this equation other than the fact that we are comparing it with the thermodynamic relation?

Comment: Saying $F = U - TS$ is a different statement than $dF = -SdT - pdV$. My question is about the latter, not the former

Comment: I don't think so. The first equation comes from the formulation of statistical mechanics. The second comes from a comparison to the thermodynamic relation, which is an empirical observation. I'm looking for a more fundamental reason as to why we can state that the partial derivative of F with respect to V is negative pressure.